# Buscar documento con regex en colecciones relacionadas con populate en mongoose

Tags: nodejs, regex, mongodb, mongoose, filtro

Tengo 2 colecciones y quiero realizar una búsqueda pero el campo en el cual quiero aplicar mi filtro esta dentro de un populate por lo cual tengo problemas para solo el resultado de coincidencia

**Nota: No agregue todos los datos de las colecciones para simplificar el código**

Esta es mi coleccion 1

```
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre del articulo es requerido'],
        maxlength: [50, "El nombre de producto es muy largo"],
        trim: true,
    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El modelo es requerido'],
        maxlength: [20, "El modelo es muy largo"],
        trim: true,
    }
});
```

Esta es mi coleccion 2

```
  const OutputSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
        article: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Article",
            required:true
        },
        registerUser: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"    
        }
 });
```

He investigado y logre que busque la coincidencia pero no lo realiza de manera correcta
Este es el código que tengo para realizar la búsqueda

```
result = await Output.find({})
   .populate({ path: 'article', match: { name: { $regex: regex } } })
```

Mi resultado es el siguiente al intenta buscar el articulo que se llama

> Lector Actualizado

La tabla excluye los resultados que no son iguales al filtro pero solo del apartado articulos pero no rechaza los demás campos de los cuales no coincide el filtro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué contiene la variable regex?

Comment: Esto es lo que contiene regex                                                                `const data = req.params.searchData;
 const regex = new RegExp(data, 'i');`

Comment: No hay forma que se filtre el documento padre (`Output`) por atributos del documento hijo (`Article`). Por lo cual tendrás que filtrar los resultados manualmente. Es parte del comportamiento esperado de `populate`. Si deseas los resultados filtrados desde la base de datos, podrías hacer un proceso de agregación, que tal vez sea lo que se ajuste a este caso particular. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea filtrar una colección de documentos (`Output`) en base al campo de documentos de otra colección (`Article`) de los cuales se tiene una referencia en el documento origen. Para realizar la agregación de los datos se utiliza el método [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) sobre el Modelo de datos de la colección. Sin embargo, si bien se realiza el filtrado de los documentos de `Article` uqe cumplen con la condición, este filtrado no se propaga hacia la colección `Output`.

Este es el comportamiento esperado del método `populate` definido en las [consultas condicionadas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) sobre los campos a los que se aplica el `populate`.

Según se tiene de la documentación:

> En general, no hay forma de hacer que `populate()` filtre *output* basado en propiedades del *artículo* de dicho *output*.

Además,en la documentación se sugiere lo siguiente:

> Si se desea filtrar *output* por el nombre del *artículo*, se podría usar una [denormalización](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3).

**SOLUCIÓN**

**Usando `populate` y realizando un filtrado del resultado.**

Tal como [te digo en mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/503306/buscar-documento-con-regex-en-colecciones-relacionadas-con-populate-en-mongoose#comment897864_503306), podrías hacer el filtrado luego de obtener el resultado de `populate`.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente consulta devolverá todos los documentos de `Output` que coincidan con el filtro de búsqueda:

```js
const result = await Output.find({}).exec();
```

Luego, si realizamos el proceso de `populate` sobre este resultado, y tal como se desprende de la documentación, los documentos de `Article` que coincidan con el filtro de búsqueda pasado a `populate` serán agregados al campo `article`, pero si no hay coincidencias se agregará `null` al campo `article`.

La consulta es tal como la tienes actualmente:

```js
const result = await Output.find({})
.populate({ path: 'article', match: { name: { $regex: regex } } })
.exec();
```

Y el resultado será: **todos** los documentos de la colección `Output`, con un campo `null` en su propiedad `article` para aquellos subdocumentos de `Articles` que no pasen el filtro pasado a `populate`.
Por ejemplo, una salida de esta consulta puede verse así:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904c"),
    article: {
      _id: ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39045"),
      name: 'Article 1',
      model: 'Model X',
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z
    },
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904d"),
    article: null,
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904e"),
    article: null,
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904f"),
    article: null,
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.234Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.234Z
  }
]
```

Como se observa devuelve una serie de documentos, pero sólo uno de ellos contiene información en el campo `article`.

Para quedarnos exclusivamente con ese documento (o con los que contengan información en dicho campo), debes hacer un proceso de filtrado adicional, descartando todos aquellos documentos de `Output` que tengan su campo `article` igual a `null`.

Para ello puedes usar el método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), como se ve a continuación:

```js
const populatedOutputs = await Output.find({})
  .populate({ path: "article", match: { name: { $regex: regex } } })
  .exec();

const filteredOutputs = populatedOutputs.filter(output => output.article !== null);
console.log(filteredOutputs);
```

El filtro aplicado, es para descartar todos aquellos documentos cuyo campo `article` sea igual a `null`. Pero la condición de filtro la he escrito de la siguiente forma:

```js
output.article !== null
```

que devuelve `true` si el valor de `output.article` es ditinto de `null`.

Así, el resultado de aplicar dicho filtro al resultado anterior será:

```js
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904c"),
    article: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39045"),
      name: 'Article 1',
      model: 'Model X',
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z
    },
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  }
]
```

Donde se aprecia que sólo devuelve un documento de todos los existentes en la colección de `Output`.

Esta es la forma de realizar el filtrado una vez que has completado el proceso de `populate`.

**Usando un proceso de agregación.**

Otra forma de obtener el resultado que deseas, directamente filtrado desde la base de datos, es hacer una petición de agregación, en vez de una consulta con `find` y `populate`.

Una operación de agregación es **costosa** a nivel de recursos de base de datos, por lo cual debemos siempre tener en cuenta el impacto de nuestra consulta y decidir si es apropiado o no.

Para este caso particular, nos apoyaremos en tres etapas o `stages`:

1. Etapa [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

Esta etapa nos va a permitir buscar los documentos de la colección `Article` que tengan una referencia en los documentos de la colección `Output`. Esta etapa se ve de la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "articles",  // <- nombre de la colección donde se va a buscar
    localField: "article",  // <- nombre del campo con la referencia
    foreignField: "_id",  // <- nombre del campo al que apunta la referencia
    as: "article"  // <- nombre del campo donde se almacenarán los resultados
  }
}
```

El resultado de la etapa anterior puede verse parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904c"),
    article: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39045"),
        name: 'Article 1',
        model: 'Model X',
        __v: 0,
        createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z,
        updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z
      }
    ],
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904d"),
    article: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39046"),
        name: 'Article 2',
        model: 'Model X',
        __v: 0,
        createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.189Z,
        updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.189Z
      }
    ],
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904e"),
    article: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39047"),
        name: 'Article 3',
        model: 'Model Y',
        __v: 0,
        createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z,
        updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z
      }
    ],
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904f"),
    article: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39048"),
        name: 'Article 4',
        model: 'Model Y',
        __v: 0,
        createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z,
        updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z
      }
    ],
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.234Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.234Z
  }
]
```

2. Etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

En esta etapa, vamos a *convertir* el valor del campo `article`, que es un Array calculado en la etapa anterior, por un campo de tipo documento embebido. Como sabemos de antemano que dicho Array tendrá sólo 1 elemento, podemos simplemente sacar ese documento fuera del Array y almacenarlo en el campo llamado `article`:

```js
{
  $unwind: "$article"
},
```

El resultado de aplicar las dos etapas anteriores se puede ver así:

```js
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904c"),
    article: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39045"),
      name: 'Article 1',
      model: 'Model X',
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z
    },
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904d"),
    article: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39046"),
      name: 'Article 2',
      model: 'Model X',
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.189Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.189Z
    },
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904e"),
    article: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39047"),
      name: 'Article 3',
      model: 'Model Y',
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z
    },
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904f"),
    article: {
      _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39048"),
      name: 'Article 4',
      model: 'Model Y',
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.190Z
    },
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.234Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.234Z
  }
]
```

Se aprecia que el campo `article` es un documento y no un array.

3. Etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

En esta etapa filtraremos el resultado pasando como filtro el operador de consulta [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

```js
{
  $match: {
    "article.name": { $regex: regex }
  }
}
```

El resultado de las tres etapas anteriores se puede ver así:

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc3904c"),
  article: {
    _id: new ObjectId("61c7478b1eea10ac5cc39045"),
    name: 'Article 1',
    model: 'Model X',
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.187Z
  },
  __v: 0,
  createdAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-12-25T16:32:11.233Z
}
```

Este es el mismo resultado que la operación que usa `find` y `populate`. Se puede escribir de la siguiente forma en tu método:

```js
const aggregate = [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "articles",
      localField: "article",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "article"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$article"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "article.name": { $regex: regex }
    }
  }
];

const aggregatedOutputs = await Output.aggregate(aggregate).exec();
```

Con esto, hemos analizado 2 posibles formas de obtener el resultado deseado.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Excelente colega, muchas gracias utilice la segunda opción mas simple y rápida ademas de que tengo no contara con muchos registros por lo que me pareció la mejor elección, gran respuesta al poner 2 opciones algo muy util la verdad!

Comment: Hola! Justo lo que buscaba, solo que pasa cuando son varios campos los que entran dentro de la consulta? Por ejemplo cuando quieres a acceder a varios campos especificos que vienen de diferentes colecciones referidas en el documento? Algo como lo siguiente  `await this.clienteModel.find({estado:true, $or:[ { nombre_cliente: { $regex: sensitiveSearch, $options: 'i' } }, { rtn: { $regex: searchValue, $options: 'i' } }]}, selectFields).populate(populates.tipo_cliente).populate(populates.estado_cuenta).lean()]]` En este caso se accede directamente, pero cuando se tenga que hacer en varios?

Comment: @Izlia te invito a realizar una pregunta para tu caso específico.